# How to get the YouTube video id in the download button without showing in the URL?

Tags: button, download

How to get the YouTube video id in the download button without showing it in the URL?

like:

http://hdjum.com/v/VGhlIEJlc3QgU21hcnRwaG9uZSBGb3IgWW91VHViZXxvVm9zUWtjbWY3THxVbmJveCBUaGVyYXB5

Kindly check this

Comment: You may need to provide some more information about what you're trying to achieve in order to get a useful answer. Currently we don't know where the ID is coming from or what you want to do with it. For example, the ID of the video on the page you linked is `bIbfDxpzs7Y`, but that doesn't appear to be in the URL. Is that your page and you want to implement the download button? In which case, you must already have the ID in order to have embedded the video. If not then what do you want to do with the ID and the download button?

Comment: I just want to download the video from video_id